# Parse Enum Extension

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an Enum extension to convert it to some kind of object:

```
var mods = RoleModel.Admin | RoleModel.Editor;

List<Role> rols = mods.Parse(x => new Role { Id = (Int32)x, Name = x.GetName() });
```

The RoleModel can be an Enum or a Flags Enum. I created the following extension:

```
public static T Parse<T>(this Enum value, Func<IEnumerable<Enum>, T> expression) where T : Object {

  Type type = value.GetType();

  IEnumerable<Enum> values;

  if (type.GetCustomAttributes<FlagsAttribute>().Any())
    values = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>().Where(value.HasFlag);
  else 
    values = new List<Enum> { value };

  if (values == null)
    return default(T);

  return expression(values);      

} // Parse
```

The problem is that x becomes an IEnumerable instead of an Enum.

How can I make my Parse method similar to a Select?

**UPDATE**

I was able to fix part of the problems ... I tried the following:

```
var a = RoleModel.Master;

var b = RoleModel.Master | RoleModel.Editor;

var c = a.Parse(x => new Role { Id = Convert.ToInt32(x) });

var d = b.Parse(x => new Role { Id = Convert.ToInt32(x) });

var e = new RoleModel().Parse(x => new Role { Id = Convert.ToInt32(x) });
```

**On c and e I am not able to cast using (Int32). I need to use Convert. Why?**

**On e I do not get anything ... I was expecting to get all values of the enum. Why?**

My current code is the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Parse<T>(this Enum value, Func<Enum, T> expression) {

  Type type = value.GetType();

  IEnumerable<Enum> enumerations;

  if (type.GetCustomAttributes<FlagsAttribute>().Any())
    enumerations = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>().Where(value.HasFlag);
  else 
    enumerations = new List<Enum> { value };

  foreach (Enum enumeration in enumerations)
    yield return expression(enumeration);      

} // Parse
```

Any idea how to solve the current problems?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: what is the point of `where T : Object` ?

Comment: To be honest, now that I think of it nothing ...

Comment: I would like Parse to be something like Select in Linq. But inside Parse x would be each Flag in the enum or the single enum if it has no Flags

Comment: If you want to make it like Select then you must write an enumerator.  You are however *not* going to enjoy using `x` values of type Enum to initialize Role.

Comment: Why will I not like it? In my application I use a few enums which I need to map to EF Entities or to View Models ... So I was looking for a flexible way to do this without repeating all the code everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement extension like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Parse<T>(this Enum value, Func<Enum, T> expression)
{

    Type type = value.GetType();

    IEnumerable<Enum> values;

    if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false).Any())
        values = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>().Where(value.HasFlag);
    else
        values = new List<Enum> { value };

    return values.Select(expression);

} // Parse
```

and use as:

```
RoleModel model = RoleModel.Admin | RoleModel.Editor;

IEnumerable<Role> roles = model.Parse(x => new Role
                                            {
                                               Id = Convert.ToInt32(x),
                                               Name = Convert.ToString(x)
                                            }
                                     );
```

or without convert:

```
IEnumerable<Role> roles = model.Parse(x => new Role
                                           {
                                               Id = (int)(RoleModel)x,
                                               Name = ((RoleModel)x).ToString()
                                           }
                                     );
```

`On e I do not get anything ... I was expecting to get all values of the enum. Why?`
To get all values you can do some trick like:

```
[Flags]
enum RoleModel : byte
{Admin = 1, Editor = 2, User = 4, Viewer = 8};
```

then use:

```
var roles = ((RoleModel)byte.MaxValue()).Parse(x => ....
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't work ... Maybe I applied it wrong. How would you do it?

Comment: Yes, I ended up solving the yield problem ... I updated my code. Still a few problems but I am not sure if they can be solved ...

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? It just declares the function with the Enum as parameter and adjusted the body accordingly:

```
public static List<T> Parse<T>(this Enum value, Func<Enum, T> expression) where T : Object {

   Type type = value.GetType();

  IEnumerable<Enum> values;

  if (type.GetCustomAttributes<FlagsAttribute>().Any())
    values = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>().Where(value.HasFlag);
  else 
    values = new List<Enum> { value };

  if (values == null)
    return new List<T>(default(T));

  return values.Select(expression).ToList();

} // Parse
```

Comment: That does not compile ... And I am not sure that having a ToList inside the extension is the best option ...

Comment: You should use if (values == null) { return default(List<T>); }. Your code does not compile. And expression.Select does not compile either. I am not sure how to solve it ...

Comment: @MDMoura Thanks and sorry, I had no VS launched, hope after the edits this will compile.