# Correct way to use String enums in C#

Tags: c#, xml

Let's say I have a directory with a set of XML files (for example, two files called ReadMacAddress.xml and ReadManufacturerId.xml) that I need to handle each one in a special way. Basically each of these XML files are a set of commands that are being received by my class. 
Suppose I have an external class that is giving commands about which file should be opened,

```
public static void test()
{
     string RecievedCommand = "ReadMacAddress"; //Command recieved from a queue
     string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
     string xml = File.ReadAllText(baseDirectory + "ReadMacAddress.xml");
}
```

To have the possibility of opening the file automatically based on which command is received I was thinking of doing the following, first defining an enum data structure with the names of the files and then using a switch case to differentiate between the different commands(name of the file that needs to be parsed) and then using this while parsing the file.

```
class My_EnumXML
{
    public enum ReadXML
    {
        ReadMacAddress,
        ReadManufacturerId,
    }
}


class TestRead
{
    public static void OpenFile()
    {
        string RecievedCommand = "ReadMacAddress";
        string CurrentCommand = SMLReadInputs((My_EnumXML.ReadXML)RecievedCommand);
        string xml = File.ReadAllText(baseDirectory + CurrentCommand);
    }

    public string SMLReadInputs(My_EnumXML.ReadXML pRecievedCommand)
    {
        string CurrentCommand = ""; 
        switch (pRecievedCommand)
        {
            case My_EnumXML.ReadXML.ReadMacAddress:
                CurrentCommand = Enum.GetName(typeof(My_EnumXML.ReadXML), 0);
            case My_EnumXML.ReadXML.ReadMacAddress:
                CurrentCommand = Enum.GetName(typeof(My_EnumXML.ReadXML), 0);
        }
        return CurrentCommand;
    }
}
```

For this example I just used the name of two XML files but I have a 100 of these and I need to know if I am proceeding in the right way, especially since I cannot debug my code because the part about receiving commands from a message queue is being implemented by someone else.

Comment: Why do you think you can't test it? Setup a test procedure for this

Comment: You receive a `string` and to open a file you need a `string` - why would you want to convert it to an enum and back?

Comment: Just an additional hint: If `SMLReadInputs()` is called many times, you could also create a `private static readonly Dictionary<My_EnumXML.ReadXML, string>` for lookups and use it as an alternative to a `switch` statement so that you don't need to call the pretty expensive `Enum.GetName()` for each and every command.

Comment: `(My_EnumXML.ReadXML)RecievedCommand` -> You can not cast a String to an Enum. You'll need to parse it, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121049/parse-enum-extension

Comment: see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11130/String-Enumerations-in-C